# I get force closed in my code for passing data from activity to detail activity

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I setting um my main activity, and I want to when I click one of the lists of my data it can display detail activity to get the detail of my data but when I have done with my code and run my app, the app got force closed if I click the list of data.

my DetailProduk class :

```
public class DetailProduk extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imgDtl;
    TextView nameDtl, priceDtl, descDtl;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    String nm, prc, desc;
    int imgs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_produk);

        // view
        imgDtl = findViewById(R.id.dtl_img);
        nameDtl = findViewById(R.id.dtl_name);
        priceDtl = findViewById(R.id.dtl_price);
        descDtl = findViewById(R.id.dtl_desc);

        imgs = getIntent().getIntExtra("imgPhoto", 0);
        prc = getIntent().getStringExtra("tvPrice");
        nm = getIntent().getStringExtra("tvName");
        desc = getIntent().getStringExtra("tvDesc");

        nameDtl.setText(nm);
        priceDtl.setText(prc);
        descDtl.setText(desc);
        imgDtl.setImageResource(imgs);
    }
}
```

My Adapter::

```
public class ListProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListProductAdapter.ListViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Product> listProduct;
    Dialog myDialog;
    Context context;

    public ListProductAdapter(ArrayList<Product> list) {
        this.listProduct = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_row, parent, false);
        return new ListViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ListViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Product prd = listProduct.get(position);
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext())
                .load(prd.getImage())
                .apply(new RequestOptions().override(85, 85))
                .into(holder.imgPhoto);
        holder.tvName.setText(prd.getName());
        holder.tvPrice.setText(prd.getPrice());
        holder.tvDesc.setText(prd.getDesc());

        // detail
        holder.relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(context, DetailProduk.class);
                intent.putExtra("imgPhoto", prd.getImage());
                intent.putExtra("tvName", prd.getPrice());
                intent.putExtra("tvPrice", prd.getPrice());
                intent.putExtra("tvDesc", prd.getDesc());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listProduct.size();
    }

    public class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imgPhoto;
        public TextView tvName, tvPrice, tvDesc;
        public RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

        public ListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgPhoto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_product);
            tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_product);
            tvPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_price);
            tvDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_desc);
            relativeLayout=itemView.findViewById(R.id.prd_list);
        }
    }
}
```

My ArrayList for keep the data::

```
  public static ArrayList<Product> getListData() {
        ArrayList<Product> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int i = 0;
        for (String[] aData : data) {
            Product prd = new Product();
            prd.setName(aData[0]);
            prd.setPrice(aData[1]);
            prd.setDesc(aData[2]);
            prd.setImage(images[i++]);
            list.add(prd);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: logcat with the full stack trace please.

Comment: I do not connect my device with Android Studio in either a smartphone or an emulator

Comment: I use the app-debug.apk to test my app

Comment: Then do that. Without proper error information it is like searching for your keys in the complete dark.

Comment: I can't, my computer processor can't run the emulator.. I use AMD

Comment: I think context is null

Comment: you don't need to run in emulator connect your physical phone to android studio.

Comment: even with my phone, I can't do that.

Comment: I think your context is null when calling intent on click item. Please check

Comment: Vote up for correct answer will highly appreciate :-)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in my context.

this is my solution

```
            @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(),""+listProduct.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("imgPhoto", prd.getImage());
            intent.putExtra("tvName", prd.getName());
            intent.putExtra("tvPrice", prd.getPrice());
            intent.putExtra("tvDesc", prd.getDesc());
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```